# Java Web Start Error FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, java-web-start, filenotfoundexception

So Im trying to use webstart on this application of mine and I keep getting this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://www.fenixflame.net/DropLogger/Drop Logger.jar  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://www.fenixflame.net/DropLogger/Drop Logger.jar  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>     ... 15 more

This is my First time using webstart. I tested it out with simple applications and it worked just fine. I think it might have something to do with the fact that the application tries to read a local file when its launched.
Cannot post more than 2 links but you can check it out here:
fenixflame.net/DropLogger/launch.html

Comment: Why is there a space between Drop and Logger?

Comment: Thats the name of the project. Maybe I should change it? Spaces are not friendly with URLs

Comment: I think this might help. There definitely shouldn't be a space in `jar` filename.

Comment: space problem indeed, http://www.fenixflame.net/DropLogger/Drop%20Logger.jar exists

Comment: Changed the name of the project but the jar file Name remains the same how can I change it inside netBeans?

Comment: Be sure to validate the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  An URL can encode a space in a name, replace it with %20.  But it is better (simpler) to not use either spaces or upper case in Jar names that are served over the web.

Comment: Yes the problem was the space on the file name. Changed that and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes problem was the space on the .jar file. I changed it and it worked just fine.
Its not possible to change the .jar file name inside netBeans, you can only change the project name but that doesnt change the file name. The only way to do change the .jar name is going to the project .xml file or creating a new project with the name you want for your jar file and copying all ur packages there.